# Picking a random amount of players from a waiting list

Tags: java

I am creating a little game and looking for a good way to sort this.

By using a `LinkedList` such as

```
private final List<Player> waitingRoom = new LinkedList<Player>();
```

Basically I want to pick 4-5 people from this list and add them in game, allowing for more than 1 game to be played at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int picked = r.nextInt(waitingRoom.size());
waitingRoom.get(picked);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) on the `List` and `remove()` the first four or five. The rest will be waiting for the next available game. By coding to the `List` interface, you can change the implementation as required.

Comment: and how would i use this to pick the first for to five? something like a loop?   for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

Comment: Using @Peter's suggestion, `int n = r.nextInt(2) + 4` is either four or five; make `n` your loop limit.

Comment: shuffling a large collection could potentially waste a lot of resources

Comment: @aldrin: I can't disagree; the performance would be implementation dependent, e.g. `ArrayList` v. `LinkedList`. A worse problem with either approach (shuffle v. select) would be a player languishing in the waiting room due to simple bad luck. A priority queue might be an option.